# SSL - Multithreaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, ssl, https, openssl

To make a multithreaded SSL web-server(HTTPS), should we use an array of SSL context assigning unique SSL context to each client or can we use the same SSL context for all the clients?

Answer (score 1):

Use the same `SSLContext` for all clients.  You use the `SSLContext` to create a `SSLServerSocketFactory`.  That's all you need.

Comment: Was thinking to let a `Singleton` hold the `SSLContext`. Is that a bad ide? The reason is the time delay and resource consumption. This is an Android app and it uses the `SSLContext` in many `Activity's`.

Answer (score 0):

SSLContext create SSLServerSocketFactory， SSLServerSocketFactory create SSLServerSocket， SSLServerSocket listen and accept on 1 specific port，  so 1 tcp port need only 1 SSLContext